# What does this default "Ambiguous Layout" warning mean in Xcode 6 storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard

When I create a Master-Detail template application in Xcode 6, I always receive this warning for the storyboard that it creates:

[image]

This warning is in the stock template, with no changes at all.

How do I resolve this warning?

Comment: You can't even add constraints there if you wanted to. Interesting question.